# Understanding bash script for getting drop down option

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have this script which reads the user input for executing some command, This is working fine.

```
User=0
Path="/root/file/"
Path1="/root/domain/samples/file"
echo "Please select k1  l3  l8  o5  s2  s1  v1"
echo Location "Select the location eg: [k1 l3 l8 o5 s2 s1 v1]? "
read User
if [ $User = kw1 ]
    then
            echo unlink file
            echo ln -s $Path/$User $Path1/file
elif [ $User = lb3 ]
    then
            echo unlink file
            echo ln -s $Path/$User $Path1/file
elif [ $User = lo8 ]
    then
            echo unlink file
            echo ln -s $Path/$User $Path1/file  
            cp -p /domain/samples /domain/samples-org
            cp -p /root/l3 /domain/samples
else
echo "Specified location does not exist"
fi
```

**Question**

I was thinking of having a drop-down as shown below eg. what would be the possible approach?

```
#./script
    Eg: Please select from the below menu 
    1. Location k1  
    2. Location l3  
    3. Location l8  
    4. Location o5  
    5. Location s2  
    6. Location s1  
    7. Location v1
Enter number: 4 
Selected o5
Configuring.....
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Are you asking if this is a good idea or for implementation help? If the latter, have you already tried anything?

Comment: This is what `select` is for.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html for examples.

Comment: +1 for giving the link as well. Please post it as correct answer

Comment: Forquare the above script is working, but I am trying to give it a drop down. So just want to know how it is done.